# React Why cant I get the authentication token from asyncStorage 'on time'?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await

I'm using react native and need the authorization token from asyncStorage. I am using async/await and looked through all similar questions and don't understand why I m not getting the token 'in time' ? Any help would be great!!

```
const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const url = `${api_root_url}/stream`;
        const getToken =  async () => {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
            if (token) {
                return JSON.parse(token)
            }
        }

        const token = getToken()
        const eventSource = new EventSource(url, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: {
                    toString: function () {
                        return "Bearer " + token;
                    },
                },
            },
        });

        eventSource.addEventListener('open', () => {
            console.log('SSE opened!');
        });

        eventSource.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
            console.log(typeof (e.data), e.data);
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        });

        eventSource.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
            console.error('Error: ', e);
        });

        return () => {
            eventSource.close();
        };

    }, []);

}
```

Comment: getToken is async which is why you need to put await. I suggest you to re-arrange your functions

Comment: I am putting await inside the async function infrom of AsyncStorage. I dont know why this isnt enough since the token wont be returned until I get that token because of the await. I cannot put await like this:      const token =  await getToken() so I dont know what you mean with rearranging?

Comment: getToken is async too, the rest is executed before token gets its value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `await` the `getToken()` method as well to finish reading the token.

**Solution-**

```
const App = () => {
    useEffect(async () => { //Make the entire callback function an async to use await inside it
        const url = `${api_root_url}/stream`;
        const getToken =  async () => {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
            if (token) {
                return JSON.parse(token)
            }
        }

    const token = await getToken(); // Awaiting getToken() to execute and return value before executing the next line
    const eventSource = new EventSource(url, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: {
                toString: function () {
                    return "Bearer " + token;
                },
            },
        },
    });

    eventSource.addEventListener('open', () => {
        console.log('SSE opened!');
    });

    eventSource.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
        console.log(typeof (e.data), e.data);
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    });

    eventSource.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
        console.error('Error: ', e);
    });

    return () => {
        eventSource.close();
    };

}, []);
```

}

**Elaboration on the comment by @Ozan Mudul -**

`getToken()` is an async function that returns a Promise. Promises are executed after your synchronous code because of the single-threaded nature of JS.Read more about [Event loop, here](https://javascript.info/event-loop)

In the execution phase, JS engine executes this line and adds the promise returned by getToken() in microtask queue & its reference is held by your variable `token`

```
 const token = getToken()
```

So, in the next line where you expect token to get added in the Authorization header, the constant `token` still holds Promise instead of token value.

*Awaiting getToken() method to return a value solves the problem*

```
 const token = await getToken()
```

---

**Answering your question:** "I am putting await inside the async function in from of AsyncStorage. I dont know why this isnt enough since the token wont be returned until I get that token because of the await."

```
 const getToken =  async () => {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
            if (token) {
                return JSON.parse(token)
            }
        }
```

Here, you are awaiting inside the `getToken()` method. Whenever getToken() will be executed, it's first line i.e. `const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');` will await for Async Storage Promise to finish before executing the if condition in next line. Its not the same promise returned by your async method

This ensures you have the token before returning it. But this doesn't ensure execution of `getToken()` method itself. So, you have to await getToken as well then executing it.

Comment: thank you. I cannot do what you suggested (making the entire callback async as it interferes for some reason with ngrok that i am using) so I did this:  const asyncFunction = async () => {await getToken()} asyncFunction() However im still getting the same error

Comment: This results in same thing because you are creating a async function and not awaiting for the response.

Comment: Another approach that you can take if you can't make the callback method async is to use then() block on getToken() method. And write all the code below it inside the then block

Comment: How can I do it ? let token; getToken().then((val) => {token = val}) doesnt assign the token in time. when I log val i do see the token but after assigning token is null

Comment: Write all your statements inside this then block. Add token to Authorization header and add event listeners inside this then block